# If a question gets closed does it cause reputation loss?

Tags: support, reputation, closed-questions

If a question has been closed for some reason like "exact duplicate" or off-topic, etc., does it cause reputation loss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closure doesn't, and deletion doesn't immediately change the headline value displayed on the site, but it will if and when your reputation is recalculated.

This works both ways of course. If your post was down-voted you won't get the reputation back either.

I wouldn't ask for a recalculation too eagerly though, as these things tend to more or less balance out over the long run.

You can see an accurate value by checking the `/reputation` page on the relevant site.

Comment: "and deletion doesn't immediately" - Depends where you are looking.  `/reputation` will show right away.

Comment: If your question gave you negative reputation, you will actually gain that reputation back if the question is deleted and your reputation is recalculated.

Comment: @Jjnguy - good point - I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Hox - I should mention that as well.